Unable to reach remote container port behind VPN - Linux
I have a small server which acts as an OpenVPN server and a ZNC server, among other things. The ZNC server runs in a docker container and is accessible locally via the server host IP.
Server IP: 172.12.0.118
Server Domain Name: vswitch0.lan
OpenVPN network: 10.8.0.0/32
ZNC container IP: 192.192.24.24
ZNC Port: 6501 / TCP
So, locally I would basically connect to the ZNC server via vswitch0.lan:6501. Unfortunately no matter what I have tried so far, 6501 looks to be closed from behind the VPN.
Some context from the server side:
[vswitch0:~$ sudo iproute show default via 172.12.0.1 dev eth0  metric 202
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 scope link  src 10.8.0.1
172.12.0.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 172.12.0.118
172.12.1.0/24 dev eth1 scope link  src 172.12.1.1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link  src 172.17.0.1
192.192.24.0/24 dev br-c36ba2fb1e97 scope link  src 192.192.24.1 vswitch0:~$


vswitch0:~$ ifconfig br-c36ba2fb1e97 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:3A:17:A0:E7 
          inet addr:192.192.24.1  Bcast:192.192.24.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:3aff:fe17:a0e7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:322161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:421089 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:31076090 (29.6 MiB)  TX bytes:58399390 (55.6 MiB)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:4F:64:2E:A2 
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:DA:E9:5A 
          inet addr:172.12.0.118  Bcast:172.12.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:feda:e95a/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd51:1367:3bc8:59a0:20c:29ff:feda:e95a/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2860148 errors:0 dropped:465598 overruns:0 frame:463
          TX packets:1922097 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1489537504 (1.3 GiB)  TX bytes:1374257854 (1.2 GiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:AD:82:55:02:0E 
          inet addr:172.12.1.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcad:82ff:fe55:20e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:282 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:19740 (19.2 KiB)  TX bytes:25994 (25.3 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:468 (468.0 B)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00 
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::2aeb:2647:2f9a:57b6/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1470  Metric:1
          RX packets:42219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:49207 errors:0 dropped:589 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:2000
          RX bytes:25138666 (23.9 MiB)  TX bytes:49238186 (46.9 MiB)

vethb25d25a Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B6:43:96:F6:F4:FD 
          inet6 addr: fe80::b443:96ff:fef6:f4fd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:322161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:421379 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:35586344 (33.9 MiB)  TX bytes:58419786 (55.7 MiB)

vswitch0:~$

iptables rules
/home/admin # iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2393K packets, 394M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  441 28422 DNAT       6    --  *      *       172.12.0.0/24        172.12.0.118         tcp dpt:6501 to:192.192.24.24:6501
    7   420 DNAT       6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:6501 to:172.12.0.21:6501
  202 83466 DOCKER     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 711K packets, 114M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 27850 packets, 1842K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1123 packets, 67032 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
  100  6012 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      !br-c36ba2fb1e97  192.192.24.0/24      0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      eth1    10.8.1.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      eth0    10.8.1.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           
    2   120 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      eth1    10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           
 6499 1829K MASQUERADE  0    --  *      eth0    10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           
2119K  195M MASQUERADE  0    --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
14719  741K MASQUERADE  0    --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   77  5532 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      eth0    172.12.0.0/24        0.0.0.0/0           
   77  5532 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      eth1    172.12.1.0/24        0.0.0.0/0           
  689 43270 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  br-c36ba2fb1e97 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
/home/admin #  iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2732K packets, 1566M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
10881  935K ACCEPT     0    --  tun+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 835 packets, 45836 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
4930K 1167M DOCKER-USER  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4930K 1167M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     0    --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2596K  668M ACCEPT     0    --  *      br-c36ba2fb1e97  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3595K 1434M ACCEPT     0    --  *      br-c36ba2fb1e97  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  713 50334 DOCKER     0    --  *      br-c36ba2fb1e97  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4973K  947M ACCEPT     0    --  br-c36ba2fb1e97 !br-c36ba2fb1e97  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  br-c36ba2fb1e97 br-c36ba2fb1e97  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun1   tun0    10.8.1.0/24          10.8.0.0/24          ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun1   eth1    10.8.1.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun1   eth0    10.8.1.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun1   eth0    10.8.1.0/24          172.12.0.0/24        ctstate NEW
    2   120 ACCEPT     0    --  tun0   eth1    10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
5890M 3889G ACCEPT     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 8811 2753K ACCEPT     0    --  tun0   eth0    10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun0   eth0    10.8.0.0/24          172.12.0.0/24        ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun0   eth1    10.8.0.0/24          172.12.1.0/24        ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun1   eth1    10.8.1.0/24          172.12.1.0/24        ctstate NEW
    8   864 ACCEPT     0    --  *      tun+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  203  9308 ACCEPT     0    --  tun+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 321K   24M ACCEPT     0    --  eth1   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  eth0   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1427K packets, 1087M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
10179  984K ACCEPT     0    --  *      tun+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  0    --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2181K  348M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  0    --  br-c36ba2fb1e97 !br-c36ba2fb1e97  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4930K 1167M RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       0    --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       0    --  *      br-c36ba2fb1e97  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2181K  348M RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  11M 3751M RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
/home/admin #

OpenVPN Server config
port 443
proto udp
dev tun0
fast-io
txqueuelen 2000
sndbuf 512000
rcvbuf 512000
push "sndbuf 512000"
push "rcvbuf 512000"
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/pki/issued/OpenVPNsrv.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/pki/dh2048.pem
key /etc/openvpn/keys/pki/private/OpenVPNsrv.key
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/keys/pki/tls-auth/ta.key 0 # As ca.crt, this is also shared with the client!
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-256-CBC
data-ciphers-fallback AES-256-GCM
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
askpass /etc/openvpn/ehmm.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 172.12.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 172.12.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.192.24.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.12.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN .lan"
keepalive 10 120
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
tun-mtu 1470
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 3

Some context from the client side behind OpenVPN:
pietro@toilet ~ $ traceroute vswitch0.lan
traceroute to vswitch0.lan (172.12.0.118), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172-12-0-118.lightspeed.sgnwmi.sbcglobal.net (172.12.0.118)  178.319 ms  178.313 ms  178.310 ms
pietro@toilet ~ $ traceroute 192.192.24.24
traceroute to 192.192.24.24 (192.192.24.24), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  213.096 ms  213.090 ms  213.089 ms
 2  192.192.24.24 (192.192.24.24)  213.088 ms  213.088 ms  213.087 ms
pietro@toilet ~ $ telnet vswitch0.lan 6501
Trying 172.12.0.118...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
pietro@toilet ~ $ telnet 192.192.24.24 6501
Trying 192.192.24.24...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
pietro@toilet ~ $

pietro@toilet ~ $ ip route show
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.20 metric 600
10.0.2.0/24 dev virbr1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.2 linkdown
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
10.8.0.5 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.6
86.31.79.20 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
172.12.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
172.12.1.0/24 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.20 metric 600
192.168.16.0/20 dev br-d252343c3ac3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.16.1
192.168.56.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.254 linkdown
192.168.64.0/20 dev br-a520ce578721 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.64.1 linkdown
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
192.192.24.0/24 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
pietro@toilet ~ $

pietro@toilet ~ $ ifconfig
br0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        ether 5e:96:85:83:a8:5d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-a520ce578721: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.64.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.79.255
        ether 02:42:bf:e6:8f:cb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-d252343c3ac3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.16.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::42:4dff:fe43:3ea1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:4d:43:3e:a1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 162  bytes 14290 (13.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 281  bytes 3123059 (2.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:bd:96:21:8b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 9c:2d:cd:5f:be:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xbe180000-be1a0000 

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1470
        inet 10.8.0.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.5
        inet6 fe80::dda0:a978:58f:e77e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 6168  bytes 1086960 (1.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6740  bytes 624579 (609.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth550a2eb: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::2c:5ff:feaf:3e9d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:2c:05:af:3e:9d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 502  bytes 65645 (64.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 606  bytes 3170670 (3.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethad57629: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::d8c0:ffff:fe9b:9cd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether da:c0:ff:9b:09:cd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 304  bytes 45543 (44.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 488  bytes 72804 (71.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:dd:38:7c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        ether 52:54:00:d6:bf:2f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:47:68:a9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:4d:70:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2001:1260:312:80e6:75ab:9a69:139b:7140  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:1260:312:80e6:be14:64fe:1a87:39d2  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::8e0a:f19e:5494:2f33  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:e9:f7:b0:5d:b5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 84957  bytes 94483506 (90.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23352  bytes 4683529 (4.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pietro@toilet ~ $

Thanks.

I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/782669/unable-to-reach-remote-container-port-behind-vpn

Apologies, I did not know I could not cross post on multiple stackexchanges. I am okay to close it if it breaks the rules.
